# Matching query does not exist when trying to edit specific object in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have created an application in which users can make bookings which are stored in booking objects. In each booking there is an automatically generated UUID randomly generated code.

I am in the process of creating an edit view and in order to do this I need to filter the view per unique_id. When I do this I get the error "Booking matching query does not exist". Please find code below.

views.py

```
def addstudents(request, unique_id=None):
    booking = Booking.objects.get(unique_id=unique_id)
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        form = BookingForm(data=request.POST, instance=booking)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
        return redirect('teachers:upcoming')
    else:
        booking_dict = model_to_dict(booking)
        form = BookingForm(booking_dict)
        return render(request, 'teachers:studentadd')
```

models.py

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    unique_id = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    coursename = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    daterequired = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    students = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    length = models.IntegerField()
    matches = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name='matches')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.slug = slugify(self.coursename)
        super(Booking, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

forms.py

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        exclude = ['user', ]
        widgets = {
            'students': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Number of Students'}),
            'length': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'placeholder': 'Time needed in hours'}),
            'coursename': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'placeholder': 'Name of your course for students'}),
        }
        labels = {
            'daterequired': 'What date and time do you require?',
            'coursename': 'Name of Upcoming Course'
        }
```

urls.py

```
    path('teachers/', include(([
        path('', teachers.QuizListView.as_view(), name='quiz_change_list'),
        path('choose/', teachers.choose, name='choose'),
        path('book/', teachers.book, name='book'),
        path('addstudents/', teachers.addstudents, name='studentadd'),
        path('upcoming/', teachers.upcoming, name='upcoming'),
    ], 'classroom'), namespace='teachers')),
]
```

Essentially within the upcoming view you will see a list of upcoming bookings. You can click add students which will take you to the addstudents view to edit your booking. This is when I am getting my error. Can anyone help me?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't including the uuid in the URL. that means that `unique_id` is `None` in the view, so `Booking.objects.get(unique_id=unique_id` isn't going to work.

You can add the `unique_id` uuid to the URL with:

```
path('addstudents/<uuid:unique_id>/', teachers.addstudents, name='studentadd'),
```

See the docs on the [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#url-dispatcher) for more info.

Since `unique_id` is required in the view, I would remove the `=None` default. I would also use the `get_object_or_404` shortcut so that you don't get a server error when the booking does not exist.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def addstudents(request, unique_id):
    booking = get_object_or_404(Booking, unique_id=unique_id)
    ...
```

You should also exclude `unique_id` from the fields on your `BookingForm`, since you don't want it to be editable.

Comment: Thanks again - I have amended my code to this and now when loading upcoming view I receive the error - "NoReverseMatch at /teachers/upcoming/" and further = "Reverse for 'studentadd' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['teachers\\/addstudents\\/(?P<unique_ud>[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})$']"

Comment: When you reverse the URL in the python code or template you now need to provide the `unique_id`. Your question doesn't include any code that does that. Note the typo in `unique_ud`.

Comment: Okay so i have included this in my code and updated above. However the custom edit link is only being created for the first object in the database. Why is this? View template above updated.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but that sounds like a different problem to your original question. I can't see what the issue is. Note that looping through `{% for bookings in booking %}` is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

**"Matching query does not exist"** this usually comes when you try to access a object which doesn't exist . In your case I think unique_id is None hence there is no query like

```
Booking.objects.get(unique_id=None)
```

Please debug it, make sure its not none and do some exception handling .